# Alternative to getting "User cannot change password" through the userAccountControl enum?

Tags: c#, active-directory, c#-2.0, windows-server-2012-r2

As far as I've been able to piece together setting the checkbox "User cannot change password" in Active Directory is supposed to result in the Property "userAccountControl" having the bit 0x40 set.

Unfortunately as I'm testing this on Windows Server 2012 R2 the bit doesn't get set for some reason.

Is there another way to? Determine whether or not a user can change his Password? Or are there some conditions/restrictions that explain this mysterious effect?

I'm using c# .NET 2.0

```
public enum EUserAccountControl : int
{
    //SNIP
    PASSWORD_CANT_CHANGE =              0x00000040,
    //SNIP
}

// SNIP

DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(searchRoot);
srch.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + accountName + ")";
var result = srch.FindOne();
var entry = result.GetDirectoryEntry();
return ((EUserAccountControl)entry.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value & EUserAccountControl.PASSWORD_CANT_CHANGE) == 0;
```

Comment: Please show the code you are testing this with.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set this property through UAC...  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305144